# what will be the default value of an uninitialized boolean value in c++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a struct called foo_boolean that contains some boolean values:

```
struct foo_boolean {
    bool b1;
    bool b2;
};
```

If I define a variable of type foo_boolean without initializing it, what will the default value of the member variables be? (i.e., true, false, or a random value of the two.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It depends on how you create it. If the struct is constructed by *default-initialization* e.g.

```
void foo () {
  fool_boolen x;   // <---
```

then the values will be **undefined** (bad things will happen if you read it before setting a value).

On the other hand, if the struct is constructed by *value-initialization* or *zero-initialization* e.g.

```
fool_boolen x;   // <--

void foo2 () {
  static fool_boolen y; // <--
  fool_boolen z = fool_boolen();  // <--
```

then the values will be zero, i.e. **false**.

Answer (score 12):

The value of the `bool` will is undefined. It will be whatever else was on the stack before it, which is sometimes zeroed out if nothing has used it previously.

But again, it is undefined, which means it can be either true or false.

If you need a default value, you can do:

```
struct fool_bool {
  bool b1;
  bool b2;
  fool_bool() {
    b1 = true;
    b2 = false;
  }
};
```

This makes b1 true by default, and b2 false.

Answer (score 6):

From Standard docs, *3.9.1.6.*

> Values of type bool are either true or false.47)

*47)*

> Using a bool value in ways described by this International Standard as “undefined,” such as by **examining the value of an uninitialized automatic
>   variable**, might cause it to **behave as if it is neither true nor false.**

So, it is undefined..

Answer (score 4):

It will produce random numbers, Why? because i tested it with g++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct fool_bool
{ 
    bool a;
bool b;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
fool_bool fb1;
cout << fb1.a << " : " << fb1.b << endl;
}
```

the first test showed me 121, 235 and the second one showed me, 34, 331
so it will be easy to figure it out!

Comment: Did your compiler change your ` : ` to a `, `?

Comment: It's a shame that this post has been given so many down votes.  While not being stated clearly, this answers the OP's question by showing that the value will be undefined.  While some explanation would have been nice, his answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean `bool` the initial value is **unknown**.

Comment: it's known - either true or false, but undefined

Comment: @Chris no, it's not even guaranteed that the bool has any value at all. It may contain a bitpattern that represents neither true nor false.

Comment: @Johannes: yeah, I read the answer that mentions the Standard after I wrote my comment. Would be interesting to find an architecture that makes this possible.

Comment: @ChrisBednarski I stumbled over that very case today, in fact. (Which lead me here in the first place).
The first condition was `if (variable && somethingElse)` which evaluated to `false`, while the next condition `else if (variable)` evaluated to `true`.

The debugger claimed the value to be 42 and it only happened while transferring language data to an external device.

Now try to debug that! :D

(Oh and it was on an ARM7 platform)

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding,

if u declare the object as global or static then the values should be initialized to false.

Otherwise the values are not initialized (basically could be either true/false).

Comment: why it will be initizlized to false when it is declared as global or static?

Comment: @Haiyuan: The Standard says "objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized".

Comment: As stated by the comments in @MBZ's answer, this is not correct. A boolean can be "unknown", i.e. neither true nor false. Actually I didn't know this until I observed it a few minutes ago. Comparing such a bool  with true or false always returned true (although I don't know if it's specified or depends on the compiler). Pretty weird!

Answer (score 0):

As many already said, in this case, the value of `bool` will be **undefined**.

On top of that `bool` being *implementation dependant* you can hardly guess what might be the outcome knowing that on top of that the `bool` will take the value on the stack.

If we assume that we have 1 byte to store the  `bool` and that we have 0 for false and otherwise for true, you will have:

- probability of 254/255 of getting a true
- probability of 1/255 of getting a false

So with **that specific implementation**, even though you won't know for certain, you will **probably** get a true (of course it also depends on what was on that position in the stack).

But it's just conjecture at this point: the answer is **undefined** as said by everyone else.

You will have either `true`or  `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting when I created a struct with two booleans

```
struct test {
  bool x;
  bool y;
};
```

Added them to a vector and iterated later - only setting the value x to true and printing both of them found the default was generally '0' indicating false but when one of them was set to true explicitly the other member also resulted in a '1' indicating that the last value from stack was being used.

This could have been such a painful bug - glad was caught by some unit testing.

Answer (score -1):

In VS 2012, you will encounter error C4700 if you don't initialize the bool variable: `uninitialized local variable 'temp' used`

However, in VS 2005 it will allow you to build, but during runtime you will encounter this error: `Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'a' is being used without being defined.`